# Python: Replacing unknown number of string variables

Tags: python, string

I need to define a function to go through a string and replace all replacement fields, without knowing how many there will be. I do know that the replacement fields will be named a specific way. For example, If i know that all fields will be named 'name' & 'position':

```
Test1 = "I think {name} should be our {position}. Only {name} is experienced. Who else could be a {position}?"
Test2 = "{name} is the only qualified person to be our {position}."
```

I need one function that would process both of these the same way, with output like:

```
>>Test1 = ModString(Test1)
>>Test2 = ModString(Test2)
>>Test1
>>'I think Mary should be our boss. Only Mary is experienced. Who else could be a boss?'
>>Test2
>>'Mary is the only qualified person to be our boss.'
```

I feel like this should be simple, but my mind can't seem to get past the multiples and the unknown quantity.

Comment: You are probably looking for string fomatting: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format

e.g. `"{name}{name}".format(name="Mary") == "MaryMary"`

Comment: you can also check out regular expressions if you will be using a different format: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the `multiples` and the `unknown quantity`?

Comment: If you're on a recent version of Python (>= 3.6) you can take advantage of string interpolation, also known as f-strings: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/

Comment: Wow I feel ridiculous for posting this. I have been using str.format forever, but only changing a single variable at a time. I didn't realize it could do mass replaces. This is the easiest thing. I'm sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def ModString(s, name_replacement, position_replacement):
    return s.replace("{name}",name_replacement).replace("{position}", position_replacement)
```

Then:

```
Test1 = ModString(Test1, "Mary", "boss")
Test2 = ModString(Test2, "Mary", "boss")
```

or you can just use `.format()`, which is recommended

```
def ModString(s, name_replacement, position_replacement):
    return s.format(name=name_replacement, position=position_replacement)
```

Answer (score 0):

str.format()    I got too in my head about this.

Answer (score 0):

bphi is right, use string formatting
e.g.

```
test1 = "I think {name} should be our {position}. Only {name} is experienced. Who else could be a {position}?"
test1.format(name="Bob", position="top cat")
> 'I think Bob should be our top cat. Only Bob is experienced. Who else could be a top cat?'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use replace() Method,  for example, read here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm

```
Test1 = "I think {name} should be our {position}. Only {name} is experienced. Who else could be a {position}?"
Test2 = "{name} is the only qualified person to be our {position}."

def ModString(str, name, position):
    str = str.replace("{name}", name)
    str = str.replace("{position}", position)
    return str
Test1 = replaceWord(Test1, "Mary", "boss")
Test2 = replaceWord(Test2, "Mary", "boss")
```